# FTP from Linux to Windows server

Tags: windows, sftp

I'm writing a script to do a `sftp` to Windows (Server) from a Linux machine. I wanted the script to run without manual inputs like inputting password etc.

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='10.x.x.x'
USER='user'
PASSWD='passwd'

sftp $USER@$HOST
```

I'm using [freeftpd](http://www.freesshd.com/?ctt=download) as a SFTP server on the Windows machine. From the Linux end as of now I'm using Ubuntu but my actual requirement will be for a stripped down version of Linux for an ARM based machine.

From the Linux machine I'm generating public and private keys using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. Two files (public and private) get generated under the `/home/user/.ssh` directory, i.e. `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`.

If its another Linux machine I'm aware that I have to append the public key (`id_rsa.pub`) to the `authorized_keys` file.

I'm not sure now, since my SFTP server is on Windows. After installing freeFTPd I checked in `C:\Program Files\freeFTPd\` , but I dont see any files resembling `.ssh/authorized_keys` as in Linux.

FreeFTPd has the option to generate a private key. So I generated one and copied the same to the Linux machine (`.ssh/id_rsa`) file and tried . But it still prompts for password.

How can I solve this.

Comment: Your question is about FreeFTPd, which is a Windows program. The problem isn't making Linux interact with Windows, but about making Windows support a non-Unix-specific network protocol. So it is off-topic here. I've flagged it for migration to [su] (do not repost).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Windows, but you seem wrong in that:

- *SFTP* don't mean *Securised implementation of simple FTP protocol* but *SSH File Transfert Protocol* so the server needed don't have to answer *FTP* protocol, but *SSH*! (From wikipedia:)

  > ### SSH File Transfer Protocol
  >
  > From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
  >   Jump to: navigation, search
  >   Not to be confused with **Simple File Transfer Protocol**.
  >   In computing, the **SSH File Transfer Protocol** (also **Secure File Transfer Protocol**, **Secure FTP**, or **SFTP**) is a network protocol that provides file access, file transfer, and file management functionalities over any reliable data stream. It was designed by the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) as an extension of the Secure Shell protocol (SSH) version 2.0 to provide secure file transfer capability...

So you have to install a *SSH Server* on your windows.

Take a look at:

- http://www.openssh.com/portable.html (you may have to install cygwin)
- http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Actually, "secure FTP" is a standard way of referencing the SFTP protocol. SFTP is not FTP, but SFTP is also not SSH (it is an IETF extension).

Comment: @ChrisDown Please show references! Or take a look at http://www.google.com/search?q=sftp or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: FTP, SFTP (file transfer over SSH), and FTPS (Secure FTP) are all different.  In other words, the answer here is correct if the OP is talking about SFTP and not getting confused with Secure FTP (FTPS).

Comment: @EightBitTony Question stand for *SFTP*, talk about `.ssh/` and `id_rsa.pub`. This concern *SSH FTP*.

Comment: FreFTPd [advertises itself as an SFTP server](http://www.freesshd.com/?ctt=overview), so there should be no need to install anything else on Windows.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, if it does the job... I don't know, as FreeFTPd seem not to be open source and as I could say same in the other way: *basic OpenSSH could does the job* as **full featured `sftp`server***.

Comment: @F.Hauri - From the article you just linked to: "In computing, the SSH File Transfer Protocol (also [...] Secure FTP)"

Comment: @ChrisDown Yes, I've pasted this in one of first edit after your post. `SSH FTP` could be called `Secure FTP` but **it's SSH anyway**!!!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way to get - password less login from a script using key based authentication. Can you please help me in this regard. Thanks

Comment: @m4n07 Did you already tried to install `cygwin` and `openssh`? I don't know `FreeFTPd`. Maybe in the FreeFTPd's FAQ would you find something.